# From a range of cells that display the alphanumeric result of a formula, use the highest numerical value only in another formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a row, let's say row 12, where 6 cells (e12:j12) display text and numbers as a result of a formula e.g. one cell might say 'UNIT PRICE: 9.83', another 'DAY PRICE: 11.62', another 'NIGHT PRICE: 6.03'. What I would like if to use ONLY the highest numerical value from these 6 cells in another formula. Is this possible? I'm using excel 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following data in Column C:

```
Unit price:33
What Price:234
Stuff Things:333
Awesome:522
Night Price:643
Im Great:44
```

One thing we could do to get the max value of the *numbers* in the cells is to first extract them into a secondary cell so we can use `MAX`. To extract the numbers we can use the following formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(1*TRIM(MID(C2,FIND(":",C2) + 1,LEN(C2)))),1*TRIM(MID(C2,FIND(":",C2) + 1,LEN(C2))),0)
```

Using `MID` we extact the numerical value after the colon. `TRIM` it in case of leading or trailing spaces. Multiply it by 1 so that Excel will treat it as a number. A little error prevention by testing that that the value returned `IsNumeric`. `If` it is numeric than return the the same formula as the `IsNumeric` test without the `IsNumeric` portion. This will return a column of numerical values.

```
33
234
333
522
643
44
```

With those values we can simply use `MAX` like: `=MAX(D2:D7)` where D was the location where i kept the numbers.